# Excel formula - How to conditionally fill a column with values from another table

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, conditional-statements

I have 2 tables here:

[image]

I want to fill up the `Code` column in Table 1 by referring to Table 2. The condition for the value is that the Start date must be in between the `ProductionDate` and `ExpiryDate` of Table 2, and the Type in Table 1 must match the Type in Table 2, else return NA. I have come up with the formula for cell `D4`

```
=IFS(AND(C4>=$H$4,C4<=$I$4,B4=$G$4),$F$4,AND(C4>=$H$5,C4<=$I$5,B4=$G$5),$F$5,AND(C4>=$H$6,C4<=$I$6,B4=$G$6),$F$6)
```

Is there a simpler way to write the formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `FILTER()` function.

```
=FILTER($F$4:$F$6,($H$4:$H$6<C4)*($I$4:$I$6>C4)*($G$4:$G$6=B4),"NA")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have found another way to write the formula:

By naming the range F4:F6 as `code`, G4:G6 as `type`, H4:H6 as `prod_date`, and I4:I6 as `exp_date`, we can use the IFERROR() and MATCH() function as below.

=IFERROR(MATCH(1,(B4=type) * (C4>=prod_date) * (C4<=exp_date),0),"NA")